# What is the best way for a Java developer to generate Javascript without writing Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, html

I am an experienced Java programmer, and Im trying to create a website with much of its content based on dynamic data from a database. The scope of the website is quite  small with only about 5 webpage designs required ( although the user will see thousands of different pages generated from the data),  but each page is quite complex.

I decided to go with plain old Java and Servlets as I understand this well, I also understand html and CSS so have no real difficultly generating the basic html pages from the data.

My problem lies with the addition of **Javascript** to improve the user interface. Ive tried using Javascript a few times over the years and always make very slow progress, if there is an off the shelf well documented solution such as a Jquery widget then I okay, but if I need to modify it or create custom Javascript I always get stuck.

Im looking for any alternative to writing pure Javascript. Im not looking at learning a new framewotk for the complete site, or for a way to abstract the html because I understand that and I don't really like deploying generated code that I didnt write.

But in the case of Javascript I would consider generated code, is there a tool that I could use to generate Javascript without writing Javascript that I could then reference from my webpages, or it impossible to consider Javascript and Html in isolation from each other.

Comment: you can use angular.js or GWT

Comment: My experience with compile-to-javascript languages such as CoffeeScript, PureScript, ClojureScript is that you can't use them without knowing javascript - mainly because the difficulty is not with the language itself but with the browser apis.

I would recommend biting the bullet and learning javascript - there really isn't any real alternative, if you want to make good UI:s. You could look at GWT, but it's not really a wise investment of your time.

Comment: Have you got a look at jquery?

Comment: Yes I'm using Jquery and mentioned it in the question, the trouble is that when Jquery doesnt offer a solution Im stuck.

Comment: I did consider GWT but decided against it in the end at least for now because looked like would require substantial investment of time.

Comment: Ive reworded question

Comment: @PaulTaylor even after rewording the title the question would fall into the [primarily opinion-based close reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10583/259228) with "too broad" lurking behind the corner. What would be the criteria for "best"?

Comment: Ok easiest then, what would someone who understand Java syntax find easiest

Comment: @PaulTaylor I've found `TypeScript` to be the safe way of writing `JavaScript` in the Java/C# style. It's pure browser-side `JavaScript` when it comes to semantics (no extra added value or heavy middleware abstractions, learning HTML5 is still needed), but it's syntax is much more class-friendly with some compile-time error detection. And it scales much better then `coffeescript` and it has very decent IDE support (refactoring/debugging)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeremy Ashkenas's public [List of languages that compile to JS](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS) lists pretty many (~hundred) options.

The section for `Java/JVM` to `JavaScript` alone lists 15 choices.

Comment: Thanks thats a useful list.

Comment: @PaulTaylor I agree. For me (considering my background and preferences) after evaluating a few options the most valuable entries on the list turned to be [SharpKit](https://github.com/SharpKit/SharpKit) and [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/)

Answer (score 1):

[Coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/) is a language that generate Javascript. I haven`t used it, but friends that develop in Javascript have told me that Coffeescript is a nice tool.

Comment: Interesting, but of course I dont know CoffeeShop either, seems kind of pointless to learn a new language just for the purpose of using another. But I could see it being useful for trying to know about some prototype code as it certainly looks more intuitive.

Comment: Look at this: [visualDesigner](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/visualDesigner/) I hope this help you.